# Change template on a cloned item in Sitecore 6.4 - does clone lose its inheritance?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

If I create a cloned item in Sitecore 6.4, then change its template to a slighty edited copy of the original item's template, will inheritance from the parent of the clone be broken?

E.g:

```
BaseTemplate      
|               |
ItemTemplate -> ItemTemplate2

Item1 (from ItemTemplate)
|
Item1 Clone (change template to ItemTemplate2)
```

Will my clone still be a clone (recieving values from its parent), or will it become a fully fledged item?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ref: [Sitecore CMS 6.4: Cloning](http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2010/10/Sitecore-CMS-6-4-Cloning.aspx)

> When you change the data template for a clone or cloned item, fields with the same IDs will maintain values, but fields with different IDs will lose values, even if they have the same names.

Considering that a clone is not a fully fledged item (because there is an option to ***unclone*** an item, which in turn **does** create a fully fledged item from a clone), changing a template does **not** "break" the clone construction.